# What is a #date# and how do you convert to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

We've inherited a VB application and are converting parts to C#.  But we're not sure how this works...

```
If LatestDate(txtSchedStart.Text, #6/29/2009#) = "Date2" Then
    txtSchedStart.Text = "29/06/2009"
End If
```

The #6/29/2009# is not a valid date - if we replace with DateTime.Parse...

Comment: It's just a date constant, which seem to rely on a specific date-setting (day/month/year). You'll likely have to take language/date settings into account when converting the code.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: If it's a constant then why would you need to take language and data settings into account? It's not like it needs parsing

Comment: Maybe they don't, but considering I have no idea what happens in LatestDate() and plus I wouldn't make dates like that in .NET / C# without making sure it's failsafe.

Answer (score 3):

If the part you are having an issue with is converting `#6/29/2009#` into a `DateTime` object, then assuming it is a constant hard-coded value you can do the following:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2009, 6, 29);
```

For extra information, the `#` character is used in VB to identify a date literal. This is the same principle as using `"` to denote a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

> The #6/29/2009# is not a valid date - if we replace with DateTime.Parse...

Per [the documentation for the `Date` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx) (my emphasis):

> ### Format Requirements
>
> You must enclose a Date literal within number signs (# #). You must
>   specify the date value **in the format M/d/yyyy**, for example #5/31/1993#. 
>   **This requirement is independent of your locale and your computer's date and time format settings.**

If you simply put the same literal into a `DateTime.Parse`, you will be using *your* locale, in which 6/29/2009 might well not be a valid date. To convert a date literal such as this into C#, interpret it as M/d/yyyy (in your head), and use a `DateTime` constructor. So

```
LatestDate(txtSchedStart.Text, #6/29/2009#)
```

becomes

```
LatestDate(txtSchedStart.Text, new DateTime(2009, 6, 29))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without taking Culture settings into account this should translate into:

```
if (LatestDate(txtSchedStart.Text, "29/06/2009 00:00:00") == "Date2") {
    txtSchedStart.Text = "29/06/2009";
}
```

You need to look into the `LatestDate()` method and see if the second parameter to be used is a string or a datetime. Depending on this, you could use `DateTime.TryParse()` or just use a DateTime

```
if (LatestDate(txtSchedStart.Text, new DateTime(2009, 6, 29)) == "Date2") {
    txtSchedStart.Text = "29/06/2009";
}
```